# How to check whether my jsp file converted to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, utf-8

I am converting all my jsp, js and css files to UTF-8.

Eg: Adding below the line in jsp

`<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>`

I want to confirm that, the pages really converted to UTF-8.

Help me to test this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add some currency symbols similar to € or © (euro and copyrights) and check whether these types are rendered.